# xml <-> html conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

What javascript framework/library may you advice if I want to convert HTML to XML and vice versa, by a set of rules?

e.g.

```
<a type="foo">
  <b>bar<sth x="42"/></b>
</a>
```

to

```
<div class="a type-foo">
    <div class="b">bar<span class="sth">42</span></div>
</div>
```

I used to traverse DOM by JQuery and build everything manually - lot of functions for every possible tag. What is a shorter solution? E.g. I want to say "`<a>` converts to `<div class="a">`" etc. and then run something like `htmlToXml()` or `xmlToHtml()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your HTML is a valid XHTML you can write an XSL transformation and apply it with javascript. Take a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember of this simple thing. A must-know tool I'm going to learn just now :)

Comment: Please don't recommend W3Schools as a learning resource. [It's frequently inaccurate/misleading](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Didn't know about it. Makes sense... Was the first google result for "xslt javascript" and seemed like a decent example.